# Using While and grep combo- "syntax error near unexpected token `<' "

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

I am trying to direct the stdout of grep to the stdin of read command in the while loop

the below code gives me the syntax error - "syntax error near unexpected token `<' "

```
while read -r line ; do
 echo "Processing $line "
 IFS=: read var1 var2 var3 <<< $line
 if [ -n "$(expr match "$var3" '.*\(BEGIN\).*')" ]; then
   echo "Found BEGIN"
   (( var2 += 1 ))
   read -r line1
   IFS=: read var4 var5 var6 <<< $line1
   if [ -n "$(expr match "$var6" '.*\(END\).*')" ]; then
     echo "Found END"
     (( var5 -= 1 ))
     sed -i -e "$var2,$var5 s/# //" -e "$var2,$var5 s%/\* %%" -e "$var2,$var5 s% \*/%%" $var1
   fi
 else
   echo "Found NOTHING"
   sed -i -e "$var2 s%// %%" $var1
 fi
done < <(grep -H -r -n Uncomment *)
```

Comment: bash heredocs use `<<`, not `<<<`

Comment: Before asking humans for help, you should run your code through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the errors that it identifies (which will be numerous).

Comment: @John1024: Nice tool, although `Load an example` shows a for loop using `$(ls *.m3u)`... not that I care or it matters (as it can be useful), but I noticed some folks getting reamed for that here earlier today... :O

Comment: I get that precise error running the script against `sh` instead of `bash`

Comment: Yup -- the OP could certainly be using the wrong shebang (`#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: or no shebang *gasp*

Comment: though, well, an example of a tool that showcases static checking *should* have some bad code. Otherwise, how would it be showing off what it does? :)

Comment: This is really unrelated to OP's question at this point, but the shellcheck example is bad code on purpose

Comment: @l'L'l   I just did "load an example" and shellcheck correctly suggests "Iterating over `ls` output is fragile. Use globs".    In other words, shellcheck was using `$(ls *.m3u)` as an example of __bad__ code.

Comment: @MarcB, those are herestrings, not heredocs; on ksh or its spiritual derivatives (including bash), the syntax is correct.

Comment: @John1024: Ah, that's such a relief! And my bad on the false alarm...

Comment: Could you add some sample input to the script, please? Or comment my "answer"ish question below ... Thanks.

Comment: Don't use two calls to `read` when one will suffice: `while IFS=: read -r var1 var2 var3; do`. You aren't using `line` except to split it, so just split the incoming line immediately. There is also no need to use `expr` in `bash`; use the `=~` operator.

Answer (score 5):

The `< <(...)` syntax is only available in shells with `ksh` extensions, like `ksh` itself or `bash`.  When I ran your code against `sh` I get precisely the same error.

Update (or add!) your shebang to be `#!/bin/ksh` or `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: May be `/bin/ksh` or `/bin/bash` on some very popular systems (incl. MacOS). May not be a bad idea to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` when unsure.

Comment: Ah, yeah, and most linux distros now symlink `/bin` to `/usr/bin` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, came here for the same problem and it solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Running with a bash shebang will fix this issue. Place `#!/bin/bash` (or appropriate bash location `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) as the first line of your file.

If you need a way to do this in `sh` as well change your `< <()` to a `<<< "$()"` which feeds in the result of the subshell as a string, I just tested this and it works in `bash` and `sh`